# Can Frost Lance Invocation's movement penalty stack when applied by two different Warlocks?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock, unearthed-arcana

Following on from [Can Frost Lance Invocation's movement penalty stack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/97509/29385) but looking at a different scenario.

The 5E Warlock Invocation 'Frost Lance' (from Unearthed Arcana) says:

> You draw on the gifts of the Prince of Frost to trap your enemies in
>   ice. When you hit a creature with your eldritch blast cantrip one or
>   more times on your turn, you can reduce that creature’s speed by 10
>   feet until the end of your next turn.

Does this mean that if two Warlocks both target the same creature in the same round that creature's movement penalty is applied once or twice?

Answer (score 20):

No, it won't stack.

> **Combining Game Effects.** when two or more game features have the same name, only the effects of one of them—the most potent one—apply while the durations of the effects overlap. [...] Game features include spells, class features, feats, racial traits, monster abilities, and magic items.

So when a creature suffers from the same effect twice over, it will still only suffer the penalty once.

Comment: Does this contradict [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/93848/19580) about instantaneous effects?